# How to draw border for panel which is continously resizing c#

Tags: c#, border, panel

Using panel as a selection indicator . The panel changes its size according to cursor position on MouseMove event . However when I draw the border as below , previous borders leave their mark on the panel and it displays too many border within same panel . Even tried refresh() before every draw but that makes it glitchy and slow

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1.Refresh();
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}

private void drawboard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Width = e.Location.X - panel1.Left;
    panel1.Height = e.Location.Y - panel1.Top;        
}
```

Comment: try to draw border using the backgroud color just before the panel resizing then resize the panel and let the panel draw the border with the actual color. In fact you do not need the border to draw a rectangle at all.

Comment: Panel is actual selection tool indicator , the objects to be selected are buttons , drawing simply a rectangle on drawboard is giving an uninteractive feel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should never call control paint affecting methods like `Invalidate` or `Refresh` inside the control paint handler.

You can solve the original issue by calling `Invalidate` or `Refresh` after modifying the size of the panel. Note that it's better to set the `Size` property with one call rather than `Width` and `Height` separately:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}

private void drawboard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var size = new Size(Math.Max(e.Location.X - panel1.Left, 0), 
        Math.Max(e.Location.Y - panel1.Top, 0));
    if (panel1.Size != size)
    {
        panel1.Size = size;
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

A better option is to set [ResizeRedraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the selection panel to `true`. Since it's a `protected` property, you need to create and use your own `Panel` subclass. As a bonus, you can also set [DoubleBuffered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true` to avoid the flickering, and also move the painting code inside:

```
class SelectionBox : Panel
{
    public SelectionBox()
    {
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

Make your `panel1` to be `SelectionBox`, remove the `Paint` event handler, and then the mouse move handler could be simple

```
private void drawboard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Size = new Size(Math.Max(e.Location.X - panel1.Left, 0), 
        Math.Max(e.Location.Y - panel1.Top, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation too!